# Ajax submission not working in Ionic App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

When the application is tested on a device using ionic run -l the ajax submission happens but the $cordovaSqllite.execute() throws an error.

The ajax submission doesnt happen when the same application is run in Ionic View using ionic upload.

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []) 
.controller('IssueCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$cordovaSQLite) {


   var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });
   var sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS issues (queryid integer,customer text,contact text,address text,issue text,status text";

     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,sql,[]).then(function(res){});
    $scope.processform =function(){   

      $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://path to my folder/data.php',
          data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
          headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
         })
  .success(function(data) {

    var sql='INSERT INTO issues (queryid, customer,contact,address,issue,status) VALUES ('+data+', "'+$scope.formData.customer+'","'+$scope.formData.contact+'","'+$scope.formData.address+'","'+$scope.formData.issue+'","Open")';

  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,sql,[]).then (function(res){
    console.log(res.data);

    $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Done!',
     template: 'Done'

   });
  });  
});
```

}

**issue.html**

```
<ion-view ng-controller="IssueCtrl">
<ion-content scroll="true">


<div class="list">

<form ng-submit="processform()">    


<div class="row responsive-sm">
    <div class="col">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <input type="text" ng-model="formData.customer" placeholder="Name" required name="customer">
         </label>

    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
             <input type="text" ng-model="formData.contact" placeholder="Contact" required name="contact">
         </label>

    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">

             <input type="text" ng-model="formData.device" placeholder="Device" required name="device">
         </label>           
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row responsive-sm">
    <div class="col">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">

            <textarea  name="issue" ng-model="formData.issue" id="issue" cols="30" placeholder="Issue" rows="10"></textarea>
         </label>

    </div>      

</div>

<div class="row responsive-sm">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" value="Submit" name="Submit">

    </div>

</div>

    enter code here

</form>

<pre>
        {{ formData }}
    </pre>



</div>


</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: adding a plunker will place everyone in a better position to help you.